# sort map based on values which has long values

Tags: java, hashmap

How to sort the map based on Values, Which is a list, and has Long values

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
List<Long> bc= new ArrayList<>();
bc.add(new Long("2"));
bc.add(new Long("5"));
bc.add(new Long("2"));
bc.add(new Long("8"));
bc.add(new Long("9"));
bc.add(new Long("2"));

List<Long> ab= new ArrayList<>();
ab.add(new Long("2"));
ab.add(new Long("4"));
ab.add(new Long("2"));
ab.add(new Long("2"));
ab.add(new Long("2"));

List<Long> cd= new ArrayList<>();
cd.add(new Long("2"));
cd.add(new Long("5"));
cd.add(new Long("2"));
cd.add(new Long("8"));
cd.add(new Long("9"));
cd.add(new Long("2"));


Map<Integer, List<Long>>  mymap= new HashMap<>();

mymap.put(1, bc);
mymap.put(2, ab);
mymap.put(3, cd);
```

How do I sort the map to get,    I want to get o/p be grouped as  bc, cd ,ab. list bc and cd has same values and same no and ab has different.I have 100 + keys and 100 of values in one key

Comment: You cannot sort a `HashMap`. Maybe you're thinking `TreeMap`?

Comment: I want key to be grouped as 1,3 2

In key 1  list bc and in key 2  cd has same values and same no. How Can I achive this. Should I use Tree map?

Answer (score 1):

```
you use tree map to sort that.

 Map<String, String> treeMap = new TreeMap<String, String>(myMap);

 link : http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-sort-a-map-in-java/
```

Comment: TreeMap sorts the keys not values